# PhoneGap & Keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I have a problem with phonegap application and internet access detection. Code bellow:

```
    var istatus = window.navigator.onLine;

    $(window).bind("offline online", function() {
        updateI();
    });

    function updateI() {

        istatus = window.navigator.onLine;

        if (istatus) $('#istatus').html('Online');
        else $('#istatus').html('Offline');
    }
```

When I run this code in browser everythings seems to be ok. It checks correctly and also marks required divs, but the problem is when I compile the application via PhoneGap Build. I have many inputs in my mobile, when you select some input and system keyboard will show window.navigator.onLine value changes to offline. This problem doesn't occur when I open the same code in system browser (not compiled). Main question is - what the hell is going on with a keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the code and link and you able to understand the online/offline event in phonegap

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOnline() {
console.log("onOnline");
}

function onOffline() {
console.log("onOffline");
}
```

[Online event in phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline)
and [Offline event in phonegap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline)

Comment: This answer didn't help me.